# layered architecture. do it correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

I want to learn how to make layered architecture correctly. For that I need an advice.

For example project I started to write news website. I layered my project:

[image]

Is it best to do that? I'll do that angular (in web project).

And one more. Should I make one more layer for Dependency injection?

Comment: It's a good way - the "best" is subjective.  Try it that way and see what problems you run into.

Comment: @DStanley thanks for advice

Comment: you should have unit tests at every layer.  NewsWebsite.BLL.Tests, NewsWebsite.Data.Tests,... and a separate integration tests project that excercises the whole system.

Comment: @Fran separate layer for every layer? interesting

Comment: @GiorgiPilishvili Each project in your your solution should have a corresponding .Tests project for unit tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not call it `NewsWebSite.BLL` because it sounds like the `BLL` can only be used for web applications.

I would have it like this. If the company name is Contoso:

```
// This is where you can put all your common code. 
// I do not mean cross cutting concern here. By common I mean if you have 
// some contstants or enums that are shared by all Dlls
Contoso  

Contoso.Business
Contoso.Api
Contoso.WebApp
Contoso.Data

// The name of test projects are exactly the same as the name of the 
// assembly but has the word "Tests" at the end
Contoso.Business.Tests 
Contoso.Api.Tests
```

Furthermore, see the Pascal Casing naming convention I am using. This way I do not have to deal with Contoso.BLL.SomeClass.

Also, my `Contoso.Business.Tests` will reside in a namespace that matches my `Contoso.Buiness` namespace. Here is a class in `Contoso.Business`:

```
public namespace Contoso.Business
{
    public class Foo 
    {

    }   
}
```

The test for that class, I would not put it into `Contoso.Business.Tests` namespace (I am not talking about the DLL). I would make my test class which is testing `Foo` like this:

```
// See the namespace here, I am not using Contoso.Business.Tests
public namespace Contoso.Business
{
    // The name of the class is identical to the name of the class being tested but the word "Tests" appended
    public class FooTests 
    {

    }   
}
```

That way they share the same namespace and I can relate them easily.

Comment: nice advices. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use often that architectural structure. In the same situations, meaning webAPI and angular.

But it's important that you considerate all the need in your project, including it's dimension. Ex: if you don't really have the need to manage Logic of business, using a BLL may just no be relevant.